# Memory management AIR IOS

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-management

I am building an app in flash cs6 that is very video based... I am using a lot of videos and images....now When I debug it I get 68 mb of file size and in task manager it uses from 70 mb to - 150 mb of ram which is a lot... can anybody give me any suggestions help on how to better memory manage the app....I have a lot of stuff embedded

these are the things I am already doing..

- I am using FLV videos at 1024 * 768 there are about 15-20 of the videos and each is about 1 mb to - 6 mb each
- I am using addChld and removeChild so each time a video finishes playing I get rid of it..i also remove its even listeners 
  -I am using all png images
- I am also removing sounds after they finish playing

Answer (score 0):

Try it on youre device it may take less ram.

Comment: @tailedmouse or if you have  a jailbroken license you could compile with these http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-Adobes-iPhone-Packager-without-an-Appl/step2/Exporting-the-App/

Comment: hehe thx for the link. It may be helpful in the future but right now I need to publish it properly.